# Angular radio button scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a radio button list where a user can select from a pre-populated list of problems, or select an "other" radio button and then type in their specific problem.

I can get the pre-populated list of radio buttons to work and set the problem (outputting the scope variable confirms this), but introducing the "other" functionality is stumping me. When I select other, it doesn't seem to bind to the scope variable. I noticed in the dom it's missing an class="ng-scope" that the other radio buttons seem to get from the ng-repeat, but I'm not sure if that's the problem.

```
        <form>

          // This part loops through the list of problems and makess radio buttons
          <div ng-repeat="problem in selectedType['nature_of_problem']">
              <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.natureOfProblem" ng-value="problem"/>
          </div>

          // Ideally this part is where the "other" radio is, it's still in the form
          <input type="radio" ng-model="natureOfProblem" ng-value="other" ng-checked="">

        </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3794/

I saw a few issues, among them:

- Using ng-value instead of plain old value for "other"
- Using a primitive instead of dot notation (if you want your view to reliably write a variable, it needs to be something.yourVariable instead of just plain old yourVariable)

Hope this helps!

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.uiState = {};
    $scope.uiState.natureOfProblem = 1;
    $scope.selectedType = {};
    $scope.selectedType.nature_of_problem = [1,2,3];
}

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>Nature of problem is: {{uiState.natureOfProblem}}</p>
    <form>
        <div ng-repeat="problem in selectedType['nature_of_problem']">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="uiState.natureOfProblem" ng-value="problem"/><span ng-bind="problem"></span>
        </div>

        <input type="radio" ng-model="uiState.natureOfProblem" value="Other" /><span>Other</span>

    </form>
</div>
```

EDIT to answer OP's questions:

I tend to use ng-bind out of habit -- in slower browsers like Firefox, it keeps "{{blah}}" from showing up on the screen as everything loads. Newer versions of Angular also have ng-cloak for this purpose, which I should probably get in the habit of using instead. :) (I also vaguely remember reading that "{{blah}}" can cause issues in IE, but I very possibly made that up.)

The use of dot notation relates to the fact that Angular can't maintain data bindings on brand-new objects. To try to explain it without using terms like "scope" and "inheritance": If you influence an existing object by changing yourObject.anAttribute, the overarching object consistently exists throughout that process and does not drop its binding. But if you have blahVariable that is equal to 8, and you set blahVariable equal to 7, you've basically tossed the old piece of data and created a new piece of data entirely. This new piece does not maintain the binding, so the controller never gets the memo from the view that the value has changed.

Sometimes I find this useful, actually -- you can briefly manipulate a variable in the view for some quick-and-dirty purpose without the controller finding out about it. :)

Comment: Awesome, very much appreciated!

Can you link to or explain the rationale behind using dot notation? I saw the egghead screencast on it, but still not sure why it's preferable.

Comment: Also why did you use <span ng-bind> rather than just {{problem}}?

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your questions, as it's too long to fit into this here teeny box.

Comment: (Also, if you found my answer helpful, please accept it. I'm a Stack Overflow noob and could use the cred.)

Comment: Thanks for further explaining your response. This answer did work for me, so I appreciate it!